# Filter out numbers larger than 100 in a file

Tags: ksh, aix

I am having large file with numbers each at a line and I just need to list the numbers higher than 100 in this file

I know some while/if that could help in this but I still need the most summarized one liner for example awk command to get that output for me

Example of outputs in my file:

```
0.000
0.000
260.591
259.906
0.000
864.451
866.000
0.000
0.000
260.796
0.000
0.000
866.351
0.000
87.554
80.000
846.142
1436.716
1435.794
522.925
524.617
0.000
```

Comment: will a simple `awk '$1 > 100' INPUT.txt` suffice?

Comment: Deleted my answer since @FredrikPihl's comment is a better version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into a proper answer

Using awk

```
awk '$1 > 100' INPUT.txt
```

Bash cannot handle floats but it's possible by a little help from bc

```
$ while read; do if (( $(echo "$REPLY > 100" | bc -l) )); then echo $REPLY; fi; done < INPUT.txt
```

from `help read`:

> If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.

Comment: You should probably `$1+0 > 100` (try `echo a | awk '$1 > 100'`).

Comment: @JamesBrown - probably. Tried both versions and I got the ssame result so I left that part out. Might be needed for different versions of awk though...

Comment: thanks Fredrik for the answer however it didn't work for some reason -- i forgot to mention this is awk on aix